# jsonwebtoken.verify method giving error from keycloak token

Tags: jwt, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I use the /auth/realms//protocol/openid-connect/certs endpoint and hardcode the x5c public key returned from this endpoint to try to get this code working (wrapped in BEGIN RSA/END RSA tags) like so:

```
let x5c = "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";
let pemEncoded = `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n${x5c}\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n`;
const payload = verify(token, pemEncoded, { "algorithms": ["RS256"] }));
```

But I don't think I've got correct PEM and I've been at it all day trying to find how to setup this certificate for verification.  The error says "error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag".  The token is valid, but it doesn't like my certificate. Any idea what I've got wrong here?

[image: Debugger image]

What's the correct way to pass this certificate to the jsonwebtoken.verify method in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is certificate, so:

```
let pemEncoded = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${x5c}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n`;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me from a big headache. The keys were provided for me via environment variables as "RSA PUBLIC KEY" and they should be certificates instead.

Comment: Worked for me in node :)